# Using the "%" character twice in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose that I want my Makefile rule to be as follows:

For each object file ./obj/%.o, there are two files ./src/%_1.cpp and ./src/%_2.cpp that it depends on (e.g. ./obj/main.o depends on both ./src/main_1.cpp and ./src/main_2.cpp). A naive way of writing the makefile in this case is

```
./obj/%.o: ./src/%_1.cpp ./src/%_2.cpp
```

But this approach does not work ... Could any one please suggest how I could define the rule in this situation?

Also, another question I have is - suppose that you define the following rules:

```
./obj/%.o: ./src/%_1.cpp
./obj/%.o: ./src/%_2.cpp
```

Then is this "equivalent" to

```
./obj/%.o: ./src/%_1.cpp ./src/%_2.cpp
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "this approach does not work." Should work fine, assuming those source files exist.

Comment: Or, more broadly, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A naive way of writing the makefile in this case is
>
> ```
> ./obj/%.o: ./src/%_1.cpp ./src/%_2.cpp
> ```
>
> But this approach does not work

Sure it does (I'm assuming you're actually defining a recipe that should be executed, which you're not showing here).  What doesn't work about it?

> Also, another question I have is - suppose that you define the following rules:
>
> ```
> ./obj/%.o: ./src/%_1.cpp
> ./obj/%.o: ./src/%_2.cpp
> ```
>
> Then is this "equivalent" to
>
> ```
> ./obj/%.o: ./src/%_1.cpp ./src/%_2.cpp
> ```

No, not at all.  Any pattern rule that doesn't have a recipe deletes that pattern rule.  And pattern rules never combine like this.

See [Canceling Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html)

Comment: Hi MadScientist, I am terribly sorry for my carelessness. Yes. The original one works and the reason is because I made a mistake when writing it ... Thank you so much for answering my question : )